# How to use bode plot for plotting a table in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

so I have a table of an electronic filter and I want to plot the gain against the frequency how could I do that ? thanks

Comment: What have you tried? A bode plot is nothing else than two `semilogx` plots.

Comment: I'm beginner at matlab can you please give me the idea of how to do it i heard there is a bode command where u can put the num and dem or something like that .. so it has to do more with the control stuff but what i have is basically a table .. how can i have it on a proper bode plot .. and i would appreciate it any idea

Comment: If you don't have numerator and denumerator you can't use `bode` or `bodeplot`, if you already have data you need the basic plot command `semilogx`. You should familiarize yourself with some Matlab basics. The simple question "How do I plot this?" without any code is off-topic.

Comment: ok could u vote this question up i don't want bad reputation bro

Comment: I will vote this question up, when it is up-vote-worthy. So you please read [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question.

Comment: you have table of what values?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have to get familiar with command line!

Basic help for any matlab function (eg. bode) is `help bode`

Detailed help with examples `doc bode`. It gives the local version of the following page: http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/bode.html#zmw57dd0e12305

//If you have jw so in your transfer characteristic and it causal you can change it to s (jw=s)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: you get the coefficients from the transfer function and you can plot it like in the link.

Comment: which transfer function?

Comment: (s)he has in that table

Comment: and how do you know that?

Comment: give me an example table!

Comment: He has a table of filter structures, with TF. As it used to be... I think